# Returning an object with a foreign key in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, object, pdo

I'm pretty new on PHP object and I was wondering something who's not in my book.

My problem is, in my database I have a table "Users" with a foreign key from my table "Ranks", and I want to convert that into a PHP Object, so I made my class on this way :

```
class User
{
    // Attributs
    private $erreurs = [],
              $id,
              $pseudo,
              $password,
              $rang, // Here is the foreign key
              $mail,
              $avatar,
              $dateInscription;
}
```

So, I also have a function to get every users from my table and list them, the problem is : how returning properly the rank of my user ?

Actually I do it on this way by linking my two tables on the SQL and I get the data I want on my rank table :

```
public function GetAllUsers($debut = -1, $limite = -1)
    {
        $requete = 'SELECT u.id, u.pseudo, rd.libelle FROM users u, references_detail rd WHERE rd.clef = u.rrang ORDER BY u.pseudo';

        // Vérification des paramètres
        if ($debut != -1 || $limite != -1)
          $requete .= ' LIMIT '.(int) $limite.' OFFSET '.(int) $debut;

        $requete = $this -> db -> prepare($requete);
        $requete -> setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_PROPS_LATE, 'User');
        $requete -> execute();

        $listeUsers = $requete -> fetchAll();

        $requete -> closeCursor();

        return $listeUsers;
    }
```

Is it a good way to do it or it's better to return an instanciation of a user and instanciate a rank on my object user ?

Actually I do User -> GetRank() to display it on the screen, as an object I think it's better to do User -> Rank -> GetName() but I don't know how to return this kind of object from my function :/

Comment: Do not roll your own ORM. There are many well-established ORM systems out there. Check out [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/index.php) for example.

Comment: You should look into using proper `JOIN`'s in your query instead of defining multiple, comma separated tables.

Comment: @BenM Thanks for the advice, but after a bad experience in Java with Hibernate I prefer to do my little "ORM" myself for my little project :)

Comment: @BenM Do you have any other favorite ORMs? I haven't heard about that one before and I'd like to add it to a list of recommendations for people.

Comment: I’ve been on board with the RedBean project for a couple of years. It’s a fantastic abstraction from the more complex ORM libs that are already built into many frameworks. As it happens, I was a big fan of Eloquent for years, but the simplicity of RedBean makes it ideal for smaller projects in my opinion.

Comment: When you instanciate a new user, your constructor could query the database for it's rank and put that value in the $rang variable.  This way you do now have to explicitly call any function to do it.

Comment: @Nic3500 Thanks ! I will try to do it ! :)